# Generalization of permutation matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

For integers $n$ and $k$, I am interested in $n\times n$ matrices with exactly $k$ non-zero entries in each row and each column. The case $k=1$ corresponds to [(generalized) permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix).

In what context have these matrices been studied? Also, is there an easy formula for the total number of such matrices (if the non-zero entries are restricted to be one)? For $k=1$, the answer would be $n!$.

For small values of $n$ and $k=1,\ldots,n$, I find

- $n=1$: 1
- $n=2$: 2, 1
- $n=3$: 6, 6, 1
- $n=4$: 24, ...

OEIS finds these [sequences](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+6%2C6%2C+1%2C24&sort=&language=&go=Search); they are related to partitions of $[n]$ into sublists but don't directly mention an obvious connection to my problem.

Comment: Over which field is the number of such matrices for $k=1$ equal to $n!$?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I'm not sure if I understand your question. When counting the number of matrices I assume that the non-zero entries are equal to one. The question thus becomes a combinatorical one I believe.

Comment: you never stated the non-zero entries must be $1$. In generalized permutation matrices the entries need not be $1$.

Comment: I think the value $9$ for the case $(n,k)=(3,2)$ is wrong and should be $6$ instead. I updated my post correspondingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other interpretation of these objects are (labelled) $k$-regular bipartite graphs on the vertex set $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n\} \cup \{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$.  The bijection: if cell $(i,j)$ in the $(0,1)$-matrix contains a $1$, we add an edge between $u_i$ and $v_j$.  The $(0,1)$-matrix is known as the *biadjacency matrix* (or even just *adjacency matrix* if the context is clear).

They are also a special case of frequency squares and contingency tables.

Answer (score 1):

OEIS knows this triangular table as A00830; you should have looked for ´1, 1,2,1, 1,6,6,1, 1,24´ reflecting (pun) the symmetry within each row as starting from k=0.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to my own question. Apparently, the problem described in the question is open, and has been considered in the more general form of finding the number of $n\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices with prescribed row and column sums.

Three recent references I found are:

- Pérez-Salvador, Blanca Rosa; de-los-Cobos-Silva, Sergio; Gutiérrez-Andrade, Miguel Angel; Torres-Chazaro, Adolfo. A reduced formula for the precise number of $(0,1)$-matrices in ${\scr A}({\bf R},{\bf S})$. Discrete Math. 256 (2002), no. 1-2, 361--372. [MR1927558](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1927558)
- Wang, Bo-Ying; Zhang, Fuzhen. On the precise number of $(0,1)$-matrices in ${\scr A}(R,S)$. Discrete Math. 187 (1998), no. 1-3, 211--220. [MR1630720](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1630720)
- Tan, Zhonghua; Gao, Shanzhen; Niederhausen, Heinrich. Enumeration of $(0,1)$-matrices with constant row and column sums. Appl. Math. J. Chinese Univ. Ser. B 21 (2006), no. 4, 479--486. [MR2270986](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2270986)

Using Mathematica, the number of $n\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices with row and column sum equal to $k$ can be computed by brute force via

```
n = 5; k = 2;
Length@Select[
Flatten /@ Flatten[#, n - 1] &@
Outer[List, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Subsets[Range[n], {k}], n],1],
(Function[x, Count[#, x]] /@ Range[n] == ConstantArray[k, n])&]
```